# WPF ScrollViewer around DataGrid affects column width

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, scrollviewer

I have a problem with a ScrollViewer that I use to scroll a user control that contains a data grid. Without the scroll viewer the columns fill the data grid as I want but when adding a scroll viewer the columns shrink to ~15px. I was able to simplify my layout and can still reproduce this behaviour.

When binding the datagrid width to another control the columns have their normal with, but that has unsuprisingly the same effect as a fixed width on the datagrid.
I guess I'm not the first one who has this problem. How can I work around this behaviour to have my grid adjusting its size to the available space and give it's columns a propotional width?

With scrollviewer:
[image]
and without:
[image]

```
<Window x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Grid MinWidth="200">
    <DataGrid Margin="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column A" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column B" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: <DataGrid 
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
   ColumnWidth="*" />

Comment: Yes, same result unfortunately.

Comment: Remove  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" and try it out.

Answer (score 23):

Yeah, I had this problem a while ago, I resorted to a workaround, I will post here just incase its useful

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" MinWidth="200">
        <DataGrid Width="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column A" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column B" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The trick was to give the `DataGrid` a width, in this case I bound back to the containing element

Or if you don't use the `HorizontalScrollBar` you can disable it, this will allow the `ScrollViewer` to calculate a width allowing the DataGrid to calculate a width.

Comment: Grid is resized when I resize window width but only when width is increased. Any idea how to resize grid when width of window is decreased too?

Comment: Thank you for this fine example of how to fix a bit of XAML using XAML. ^^

Comment: This proposed solution crashes VS2010 :-) Looks like a bug

Comment: @mardok I fixed your problem by binding to the `ScrollContentPresenter`'s ActualWidth using a RelativeSource binding.

Comment: As already mentioned, it works only when the width is increased. The way I could bring it to work is with @BradleyUffner 's help:
`<Grid x:Name="grid" MinWidth="400" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}">
 <DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test3" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
</Grid>`

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same thing last week.

Typically, this problem occurs when you have the following elements :

1. A `DataGrid` with undefined width placed inside a `ScrollViewer` with the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property set to `Auto`
2. At least one `DataGridColumn` has an unlimited/undefined width (e.g : `Width="*"`)

Actually, the solution depends on your needs :

- Either you want your `DataGridColumns` to take all the available space of your `DataGrid` when the Window is showing (even if there's no displayed data) : in this case, **sa_ddam213**'s answer can help you to cope with.
- Or you don't mind having some blank spaces between your last column and the `DataGrid` right border on Window's first show.

For the last option, you just need to set fixed widths for your `DataGridColumns` (or just don't define it if you don't want to, this is not very important as columns can be easily resized by the user through a double-click). In this context, your `DataGrid` can be defined without a width.

Here is an example :

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" MinWidth="200">
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column A" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column B" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

By this way, if a column content runs over the container after a column auto-resizing, a horizontal scroll bar will appear.

Comment: Setting HorizontalScrollBarVisibility of the ScrollViewer to None worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution prevents the problem mentioned by mardok.

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroll, Path=ViewportWidth}"
                MinWidth="150">
        <TextBlock Text="Other UI Controls"/>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Width="50"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

1. Bind the width of the container panel to the ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer
2. Set MinWidth for the container panel.