# WPF ContentControl width grows but doesn't shrink when wrapped in a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, width, scrollviewer, contentcontrol

I'm trying to figure out how to make my `ContentControl` to correctly scroll Horizontally (Vertically its fine at the moment). By correctly i mean i would like to see the content to stretch (expand infinitely) while having minimum sizes to which a scrollbar would appear in order for the content not to overflow behind the `ContentControl`'s area, so here's a quick introduction:

The main window is structured in this way:

- Grid (2 columns of .3* and .7*)

  - Border

    - Grid (7 rows, one set to * where ContentControl is)

      - ScrollViewer with StackPanel (purely for test) wrapping a ContentControl that has Auto Width

`ContentControl`'s Template:

- Grid (Width set to UserControl's ActualWidth, 6 rows with one set to Auto where ItemsControl go

  - ItemsControl that describes an ItemTemplate of a type DataTemplate which contains a Grid inside of which i have a DataGrid

The actual problem is that the ContentControl grows as you resize the window, but does not shrink with window resize.

Main View XAML (truncated for clarity):

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="5" Background="Transparent"  Focusable="False" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentSection}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Tempate XAML (truncated for clarity):

```
<Grid>
...
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.QualifyingDistributionsDividends}" x:Name="QualifyingItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="DTLayoutGrid">
                    ...
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DataLayout" Width="{Binding ElementName=DTLayoutGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        ...
                        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridNormalCellStyle}">
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

So what happens? `Datagrid` assumes width of the entire `DataTemplate` (well its underlying controls that are set to be `DataTemplates` size, then * column assumes all empty space. When you try to resize the entire window that holds this code it will grow correctly, expanding the * column but it seems shrinking is not "registered" and it keeps the size you expanded it to, applies a scrollbar over that and forgets about it.

What i've tried so far was to set widths for `ItemsControl`, its underlying parents like Grid etc, also setting size to `ContentControl`, `StackPanel`, `ScrollViewer` and parent Grid of that.
I've also tried using `scrollviewer`s directly on the `Datagrid` which produces an epileptic "1 million resizes a second" scenario. I've also played around with `HorizontalAlignments` 
Under certain situations i DID managed to get the horizontal scrollbar to appear correctly but unfortunately that makes my `DataGrid`'s * column to assume `Auto` Width rather then `Star` so `DataGrid` starts having an empty area to the right (unacceptable unfortunately...)

I understand that in order for horizontal scrollbar to work the parent or child of the scrollviewer needs Width set, i guess i can't work out where exactly do i need to restrict it. DataGrids NEED to infinitely expand with the main window while having first column fill all the available space.
Do let me now if you need more information on this and I will gladly answer.

Comment: Giving Width of the Grid to the ContentControl makes is react correctly but once minimum size is reached the Template overflows and no scrollbars appear, giving it a `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` does nothing, so does removing the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`

Comment: Dude...  that's far too long... we don't need your life history, just the [relevant part of your program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How is explaining an issue in detail so people understand it better a life story?
Large amount of code had to be put in due to unknown from where the issue is coming from.

I will trim down the snippets i guess...

Comment: Forgive my para-phrasing... I was just giving you good advice to help you get your question answered. Many users here would have seen how long your question was and simply moved onto the next one. +1 Well done for making it more concise though.

Comment: No worries! I was thinking this is a no easy points one so decided to elaborate on the scenario.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that this is just another case of the dreaded `StackPanel` layout problem. This problem comes up again and again and I confess that I had the very same problem when I started learning WPF. The `StackPanel` does *not* take the available size of its parent into consideration whereas other `Panel`s such as a `DockPanel` or a `Grid` (yes, that's actually a `Panel` too) do.

It's explained in the [How to: Choose Between StackPanel and DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754213%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Although you can use either DockPanel or StackPanel to stack child elements, the two controls do not always produce the same results. For example, the order that you place child elements can affect the size of child elements in a DockPanel but not in a StackPanel. This different behavior occurs because StackPanel measures in the direction of stacking at Double.PositiveInfinity; however, DockPanel measures only the available size.

The `StackPanel` should only really be used to align a number of items, such as `Button`s or other controls in a straight line where available space is *not* a concern. So anyway, the solution should be simple... just remove the `StackPanel` from the `ScrollViewer`. It doesn't appear to serve any purpose there anyway.

---

UPDATE >>>

After looking again, it seems as though you're saying that the problem is *inside* the `DataTemplate`, right? You *might* be able to fix that by setting the `ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`. That would ensure that each item remains within the boundary of the `ItemsControl`.

I'd also remove your `Binding` on the `Grid.Width` as you don't need it... a child `Grid` will take up the full space of a parent `Grid` by default. If these ideas don't work, just simplify your problem. Seriously, if you follow the advise in the linked page from the Help Center that I gave you in the comments, then you'll either fix the problem, or be able to come back here and provide a complete, but concise example that we could test.

Comment: Yeah I've added that stackpanel as a test, replacing it with just a grid appears to have similar results with a slight difference, there is at best 1 pixel when `ScrollBar` appears, unfortunately not being able to shrink `ContentControl` issue is still present. Removing it yield no difference from having a `Grid` there. Haven't tried `DockPanel` yet as i personally avoid it but i will give it a go nevertheless.

I will try to make a little repro app after i get some sleep and see if that will make a little bit more sense, maybe that will pinpoint where the problem is coming from more precisely

Comment: Problem was the `Grid.Width`. Unfortunately removing that makes all `Star` columns inside `Datagrid`s to assume Auto size instead which is what i was trying to work around in the first place since first column needs to assume all available screen space.

Comment: I've stripped everything and came to an understanding that this is just a typical issue where DataGrids inside a ScrollViewer element would not act correctly if there are any Star Width columns. That was the reason for the `Grid.Width` being set that way. I've tried a lot of different workarounds already but to no avail, i will keep looking further

Comment: It seems that http://stackoverflow.com/a/20120082/3008444 and simmilar approach of using a border around a Datagrid produces this same problem regardless if its inside or outside of the `ContentControl`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17876732/3008444 Looks like mardok also had the same issue with not being able to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the behavior I was looking for by using a `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanel`, with its rows bound to the count of the `ItemsSource` model:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding MyCollection.Count}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 ...                      
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As @Sheridan pointed out above, it seems the `StackPanel` is causing trouble. Also, credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23375262/385273 for pointing out the `UniformGrid` option.