# WPF XAML ScrollViewer doing weird formatting of existing grids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm running Windows 10 on .NET 4.5. In a nutshell I want to wrap my DockPanels in a ScrollViewer so I can scroll around for things that "fall" off the page, particularly where a user may have a small screen. I can't post a bunch of code or I'll be in heaps of trouble... So I hope this is something that's happened to someone and they have figured out what to do. Below the code images of a "without" the scrollbar and then "with" in that order. Literately the only change is the ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DockPanel Visibility="Visible">
        <DockPanel Name="MenuBarDockPanel" Visibility="Visible" DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" Height="26">
            ...
        </DockPanel>

        <DockPanel Name="MenuBarOptions" DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" Height="65">
            ...
        </DockPanel>

        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="BottomGrid">
            ....
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

...sorry for all the redacting... I don't have a choice.

[image: BEFORE scrollbars...]

[image: AFTER scrollbars...]

You can see that two of the grids get pinched up out of place. There were no other code changes. Hope someone can help. Thx.

Comment: I am not really sure what grids you are referring to, and what you mean by "pinched up out of place." Are you talking about the grids on the right?

Comment: @Carson: If you look at the top right of the first image the grid has the expected spacing but the one below it's all squished to the left. Same for the gray/white striped one: the first one is spread out and readable, but the lower one is squished to the left. All I did was add ScrollViewer and it got hosed. I can force the layout with MinWidth but that is not the optimum fix which would be scroll bars appear and formatting remains the same. Thx.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`? Also, do you have any `HorizontalAlignment` set on those grids?

Comment: Since you have to set the `MinWidth` to force the width to be proper, my assumption is the ScrollViewer affects the width of child components. A similar (seemingly unsolved in a way you find satisfactory) problem was happening here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875765/wpf-scrollviewer-around-datagrid-affects-column-width

Answer (score 0):

The first DockPanel you should set the LastChildFIll="true"

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
```

also the dock should probably be set to left, not knowing what's inside the panels

DockPanel.Dock="Left"

and the grid

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="BottomGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
```