# WPF datagrid shrinking columns when usercontrol width is stretch

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add a datagrid to a UserControl that has the main controls width set to stretch. The controls are being added to a StackPanel on the main panel and I want the control's width to stretch.

My datagrid has widths set, but unless I define a width on the usercontrol, all the columns shrink to about 10 pixels.

```
<Expander Header="Issues" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,86,4,4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsExpanded="False">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg_issues" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single">
             <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Key}" Width="60"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="60"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Summary" Binding="{Binding Summary}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time Spent" Binding="{Binding TimeSpent}" Width="70"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remaining" Binding="{Binding Remaining}" Width="70"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: What if you add a ColumnDefinition to your Grid with Width="*" ?

Comment: Didn't make any change, but thanks for the idea. No idea why this is happening. Haven't ever seen this with all the WPF tools I have written before

Comment: Any chance of posting rest of the code so I can reproduce?

Comment: Turns out this is caused by the ScrollViewer. set horizontal scroll bar to disabled and problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out wrapping a datagrid in a ScrollViewer with a horizontal scroll bar causes this problem.

I had found this question which brought me to the solution, disable the horizontal bar since I didn't need it. [WPF ScrollViewer around DataGrid affects column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875765/wpf-scrollviewer-around-datagrid-affects-column-width)

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```